Does the Earth’s Geoelectric field affect its orbit around the Sun?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electricity
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/geoelectric-field
Is the interaction between the electric field of the Sun and Earth powerful enough push the Earth or alter its course around the Sun?

As a really quick and very hand-wavy approximation, you can just look at order of magnitude type estimates.  Calculate $v*B/M_{E}$ where v ~ 29.78 km/s, B ~ 50 microT, and $M_{E}$ ~ 5.972$\times 10^{24}$ kg.  This will give you an acceleration on the order of $10^{-25}$ "m \ s^{-2}" or $10^{-26}$ times weaker than the acceleration of gravity on Earth's surface.

Actually, it's even worse than this because I think the B I should have used is that of the solar wind, which is about 10,000 times smaller...

@honeste_vivere The question doesn’t mention magnetic forces, but you’re right that they’re also negligible.

@Ghoster - The Lorentz force is not frame-invariant, so for static electric fields, you can just transform to a frame where it's all magnetic forces.  In any case, any quasi-static electric field generated by the word done by Earth's gravity will be an ambipolar field, and thus internal to the system (i.e., it cannot do external work).  It exists to balance inflow and outflow of charged particles from the upper atmosphere and it arises due to electrons being able to escape more easily than ions.

For static electric fields, you can just transform to a frame where it's all magnetic forces. No, that’s incorrect. Since $\mathbf E^2-\mathbf B^2$ is a Lorentz invariant (I’m using Gaussian units), a pure electric field never turns into a pure magnetic one, or vice versa, in any frame because that would change the sign of the invariant.

No.
The Earth may have an electric field, but it’s very weak, and the Earth is very, very, very massive$^{\text{[citation needed]}}$. The Earth is, approximately, electrically neutral as well, and so is the Sun; electrostatic forces, which would dominate at the AU scale, will be very small (especially because of the immense distance), and such a force would produce extremely small accelerations on the Earth.
